# Dual booting Windows 2k3 Server and Linux MBR

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, grub, mbr

I have Windows Server 2003 and Linux installed on one hard drive [on separate partitions]. My first partition is the linux boot partition, and maintains Grub. When I boot the Windows partition and shut down W2k3 keeps modifying the MBR to boot directly, and only to the Windows partition. How do I prevent this behavior? I rather like using Grub to make boot selections.

Comment: This site does offer help with OS related issues (as seen by the tags)

Comment: @steven. Please post your grub.conf plaese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed because the "makeactive" option was enabled for the Windows 2k3 option. Taking out that option fixed the issue and still boots windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try to nstall GRUB on the first sector of the /boot partition, not in the MBR.

Comment: Then you can copy GRUB's boot sector into a file in windows, and add it to the Windows boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the motherboard has the "boot sector virus protection" option?

Comment: Nope. Windows 2003 changes the MBR in fdisk.